# How to fix errors in all angular html files in eclipse

Tags: html, angular, eclipse

[image]

Hello guys, I am new in angular and just created a project in eclipse. At first all the .ts files were opening as a an audio file but when I install  angular plugin, the .ts files opened normal. However, the HTML files became as in the image above. Could someone help me on what to do in other to get rid of the errors.

The error appears in all html files, but the app runs.

Comment: `VS code` is the most popular editor for `JS framework's ` and many more. html file extension should be .html.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: The current version of the _Eclipse IDE for Web and JavaScript Developer_ has built-in Angular support. Do you have a different IDE package or an outdated Eclipse version?

Comment: It's not that package. The error message would still be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed Angular IDE by CodeMix and the errors were gone, this could be achieved using "Install New Software".